# Lock height/force column spillover of multicolumn subreport

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a report with a subreport in 3 columns placed in the details section.  I have tried everything to force the subreport to only grow to a certain height, forcing data to spill over into the subsequent columns.  It isn't working!  I have another subreport in a group footer that I always want to show on the page.  Instead, the stupid detail subreport prints as far down the page as it can, then only spills over a few records into the middle column, then prints the group footer subreport on the next page.  All of this data can fit on one page if the column formatting worked properly.  If I Uncheck CAN GROW on the subreport, then it just cuts off the data, rather than forcing it into the other column.  Lock Position and Size also only seems to work in the design and has no bearing at all on the formatting of the actual report.  Also, Selcting Across then Down on the columns does exactly squat.  This is what it is doing now:

```
<subreport in detail section>
detail data    detail data
detail data    detail data
detail data    detail data
detail data
detail data
detail data
detail data
detail data
<page break>
<subreport in group footer>
student comments
```

I want it to do this:

```
<subreport in detail section>
detail data    detail data
detail data    detail data
detail data    detail data
detail data    detail data
detail data    detail data
detail data
<subreport in group footer>
Student Comments
```

Answer (score 0):

place in your page footer whatever you have in your report footer with the same layout, because of page footer always shows it will force details to go to the next page.

Comment: I tried that, but the problem then is that within the Student Comments subreport, if I put the data in the details section (there may be more than one comment) nothing shows up.  If I put the data in the report header (within the subreport) it shows up, but then only shows the first record.  I'm not sure I'm explaing that well...

Comment: Update.  I placed the student comments info into the details portion of the subreport and the data is showing up (I was using a formula before, and for some reason that was messing it up). But when I added just the straight-up DB field, both records were showing up.  HOWEVER, I had to physically expand the Page Footer/Subreport to show both comments, even though I had CAN GROWN enabled on the subreport itself and the details section/DB report field.  Is this a limitation within the Page Footer... that it won't grow on its own?

Comment: could you please post a picture on your report layout, or send it to my email with saved data so I can take a look at it(otto840523@gmail.com)